# Powershell - delete all but the highest number

Tags: powershell, foreach, printers

Working on a script to delete all but the highest "Copy" printer (Microsoft and its infinite helpfulness creates "Copy" printers every time one of my remote users unplugs/plugs in a printer) on Windows 7 PCs.

I have two different printer names which get many "copies" made due to this problem.  In one case, it's easy because I want to delete all of the "Copy" printers, but leave the original printer - the one that doesn't have "Copy" in its name.  I do that by first clearing all print jobs (will not delete the printer if there's an existing job sitting in the queue), then delete all the "POS Lexmark (Copy)" printers -

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer | ForEach-Object {$_.CancelAllJobs()}

Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -Filter "name LIKE '%POS Lexmark (Copy%'" | ForEach-Object {$_.Delete()}
```

Works great.  In the second case, I want to keep the highest "Copy" number printer - i.e. if there are 12 "Copy" printers, I want to keep the "Lexmark Universal PS3 (Copy 12)" printer, but delete all the rest.  I do have a natural sort function line:

```
$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }
```

Which I can use to sort all the "Copy" printers in this case, but this

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -Filter "name LIKE '%PS3 (Copy%'" | Sort-Object $ToNatural | Select-Object | ForEach-Object {$_.Delete()}
```

won't work because I still need to keep whatever that highest number printer is after the sort.  I'm a Powershell newbie, so any help would be appreciated since a Google search has not turned anything up for me yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you place your sorted results into a variable, and `select-object` all but the last (highest) result?

```
$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }
$sorted = Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -Filter "name LIKE '%PS3 (Copy%'" | Sort-Object $ToNatural
$sorted | Select-Object -First ($sorted.Count-1) | ForEach-Object {$_.Delete()}
```

Comment: Yes!  This worked.  Thank you very much.  Been researching that for quite a while and could never get the Count to work.